# How to perform a flat spin?

Tags: asphalt-xtreme

In Asphalt Extreme, I am asked to perform a flat spin to achieve stars and stuff. What is this, and how do I pull such a move off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [flat spin](http://asphalt.wikia.com/wiki/Flat_Spin) is performed by [drifting](http://asphalt.wikia.com/wiki/Drift) while going off a ramp.

Here is [a video](https://youtu.be/U2QsLDFVIo8?si=zqgtuF0jZbdSqXwC&t=25) of someone playing the game performing a flat spin. Around the :25 mark, you can see the player performing the actual spin. You can see just as the player is about to leave the ramp, they hit the brakes to initialize the drift and rotates in mid air to perform the flat spin.

Answer (score 2):

To do a flat-spin in Asphalt Extreme, perform a drift before going off a ramp, if you get sideways enough before going off the jump you will perform a flat spin.